# How to save figures to pdf as raster images in matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, raster

I have some complex graphs made using matplotlib. Saving them to a pdf using the savefig command uses a vector format, and the pdf takes ages to open. Is there any way to save the figure to pdf as a raster image to get around this problem?

Comment: If you want to save to different format within matplotlib just use savefig("filename.png") to save to png raster. If you want to continue saving to PDF and then convert I agree with Gael to use Imagemagick

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can force individual figure elements to be rasterized like this:

```
text(1,1,'foobar',rasterized=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I now add rasterized=True to the line properties for each plot and it works just fine.

Comment: Awesome!  Now if only I could control the dpi of the rasterizing... It seems to ignore the dpi argument I passed to `figure()` and `savefig()`.

Comment: @weronika for me it works if I first set `matplotlib.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 300`

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know, but you can use the 'convert' program (ImageMagick') to convert a jpg to a pdf: `convert file.jpg file.pdf'.