# How to better rasterize a plot without blurring the labels in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, transparency, eps

I usually use `ax.set_rasterized(True)` to rasterize the figure so that it could handle transparency when saved as in `eps` format, but the rasterization also blurs the axis labels and ticklabels, so is there a way to rasterize only patches within the axis rather than the whole figure? or is there a better around for exporting eps format with transparency? Thanks.

Comment: I just discovered the set_zorder and set_rasterization_zorder, I think they would be helpful, but still digging the documentation, still any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use `pdf`? It would preserve the transparency without rasterisation.

Comment: @Avaris unfortunately I can not use pdf, but have to stick with eps, so rasterization seems to be the only way out.

Comment: Ah, yes. Looks like `set_rasterization_zorder` is the way to go. Check [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/misc/rasterization_demo.html).

Comment: @Avaris still cannot make it work, the object I want to rasterize is a ax.fill_between() object and the "zorder" trick mysteriously shift the object outside of the axis, weird.

Comment: Can you post an example? The one I tried seems to be working perfectly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As matplotlib [Artists](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist) can be rasterized, any class derived from Artist (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html) can be rasterized with the keyword `rasterized` set to `True`. So you can only rasterize your patches.

I just tried some combinations and it seems to work. However the quality seems to be not very good (see also http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg13276.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


def add_patch(ax, **kwargs):
    if 'rasterized' in kwargs and kwargs['rasterized']:
        ax.set_rasterization_zorder(0)
    ax.fill_between(np.arange(1, 10), 1, 2, zorder=-1, **kwargs)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 10) 
    ax.set_ylim(0, 3)
    if 'alpha' in kwargs and kwargs['alpha'] < 1:
        txt = 'This patch is transparent!'
    else:
        txt = 'This patch is not transparent!'
    ax.text(5, 1.5, txt, ha='center', va='center', fontsize=25, zorder=-2,
            rasterized=True)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, sharex=True)
add_patch(axes[0], alpha=0.2, rasterized=False)
add_patch(axes[1], alpha=0.2, rasterized=True)
add_patch(axes[2], rasterized=False)
add_patch(axes[3], rasterized=True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('rasterized_transparency.eps')
```

I converted the `eps` to png to show it in the browser:

[image: rasterized_transparency.png]

See also: [How to save figures to pdf as raster images in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609969/how-to-save-figures-to-pdf-as-raster-images-in-matplotlib).

Comment: Thanks, I will try your example and have it tested on my own codes ASAP. Answer will be accepted by then ;-).

Answer (score 4):

The results are better if you specify dpi - which seems to default to quite a low value.  For example, change the last line to

```
plt.savefig('rasterized_transparency.eps',dpi=200)
```

and the file grows to 4.5M, and looks fine in Acrobat up to 200% magnification.  However I agree that there are probably more compact formats that support transparency.