# Size of matplotlib contourf image files

Tags: matplotlib

I've got a contourf figure in matplotlib that is about 5 megs.  Any suggestions on how to reduce the size?

Comment: The figure occupies 5 megabytes of resident memory?  Or 5 megabytes when rasterized and written to a file?

Comment: 5 megs when written to disk in pdf format.

Comment: A PDF can be worst case for some datasets since it will typically preserve the vectors.  Though my experience is usually with scatter plots.  Try rasterizing to a PNG instead.  If that works you can embed the PNG in a PDF in a separate step.

Comment: Is there a way to rasterize the plot, but keep the axes labels and title as vector data?

Comment: Yes, apparently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5638626/489590

Comment: @BrianCain that works for some types of Axes object, but not `contourf`. See my answer for a way around this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have many elements of the `contourf`

For some types of `Axes` objects, you can set the `rasterized` option to `True` right when you call the plotting function.  For example, with `pcolormesh`, you can use

```
plt.pcolormesh(some_array,rasterized=True)
```

However, for `contourf` this does not seem to work, but there is a way around it. You can set the `zorder` to some low number, then set the `rasterization_zorder` for the `Axes` to some number above that, and when you save the figure, it the `QuadContourSet` returned by `contourf` will be rasterized.

For example:

```
plt.contourf(some_array,zorder=-9)
plt.gca().set_rasterization_zorder(-1)
```

Below, I show some example file sizes after plotting a `np.random.rand` array of shape `(500,500)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

my_array = np.random.rand(500,500)

plt.contourf(my_array)
plt.savefig('contourf1.pdf')
plt.close()

plt.contourf(my_array,rasterized=True) # this won't work
plt.savefig('contourf2.pdf')
plt.close()

plt.contourf(my_array,zorder=-9)
plt.gca().set_rasterization_zorder(-1)
plt.savefig('contourf3.pdf')
plt.close()
```

Which gives the following three files:

```
$ ls -l contour?.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom 22804867 Oct 21 10:59 contourf1.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom 22808387 Oct 21 11:01 contourf2.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom   851117 Oct 21 11:03 contourf3.pdf
```

notice the much smaller file size for the third file.